# URLConnection working very slow when using proxy

Tags: java, proxy, urlconnection

It took me a long time to get the proxy for my Java connection working at my office. Now I got it working, but it's VERY slow.

I use the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        try {
            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx",
                            "xxxx".toCharArray()));
                }
            };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
            url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xxx", xxx)));
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Duration: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-millis));
    }

}
```

When I run this, the output is the following:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
Duration: 222856
```

As you can see, the proxy is working. I do get the webpage just fine. But it's waiting very long before showing the webpage contents (more than 222 seconds :O). I have no clue what could possibly be the problem here.

Just some information about the environment: I'm working on my office VDI. Google Chrome and IE have internet connection, but other programs don't. By a lot of googling I found the correct proxy settings.

Comment: You may have a DNS timeout because of multiple suffixes added to your proxy hostname, one after the other, until you system the correct one. Instead of giving the host address in `new InetSocketAddress("xxx", xxx)`, try giving the IP address directly `new InetSocketAddress(new InetAddress(...), xxx)`. If it is faster, this would explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately it results in the same issue. Would it help to know that the line that takes very long is the *conn.getInputStream();* line?

Comment: Sounds weird => one way to debug this trouble: use Wireshark (or Ethereal, or snoop, or tcpdump) to look at the IP packets that are exchanged during this line. Specifically look at DNS packets.